# Whitelist positive double in TextInput

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to allow user to whitelist positive double number.
I.e. he tries to enter something valid like 1.22 - system allows him. Any alphabetical symbols or second . is ignored.

This solution works however still allows entering second dots:
`FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9.]'))`

This solution filters second dot however if I'm trying to enter invalid symbols - system 'remembers' it and doesn't allow keep entering numbers. I have to 'delete invisible symbols' before I move on.

`WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d*)'))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33955040/12341099, do some research before posting

Comment: Thanks. I did, but haven't guessed to use such keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d*)'))
```